# How do I make arcs rotate in a nested loop?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, p5.js

I've been struggling with this one for a couple of days now. I am trying to figure out how to make the arcs in this code rotate. I think the problem is that they are in a nested loop with random variables but I'm not sure how to fix that and still make it work.

I know I need to increase or decrease the start/stop angles in unison but to make them rotate but I need to figure out how to get static arcs once they are drawn first (i think).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```js
let data;
let index = 0;

function preload() {
  // data = loadJSON("palettes.json");
  data = {
    palettes: [
      ["#69d2e7", "#a7dbd8", "#e0e4cc", "#f38630", "#fa6900"]
    ]
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  index = floor(random(data.palettes.length));
  arcNumber = round(random(1, 3))
}

function draw() {
  angleMode(DEGREES)
  let palette = data.palettes[index];
  let combBorderHeight = 0.2 * height
  let combBorderWidth = 0.2 * width
  let borderHeight = 0.1 * height
  let borderWidth = 0.1 * width
  stroke(palette[0])
  background(palette[0])

  for (let x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
      if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 1)) {
        fill(palette[1])
      } else {
        fill(palette[2])
      }
      rect((x + borderWidth + (x * (width - combBorderWidth) / 7)), (y + borderHeight + (y * (height - combBorderHeight) / 7)), (width - combBorderWidth) / 7, (height - combBorderWidth) / 7)
      let arcNumber;
      arcNumber = round(random(1, 3))

      for (let i = 0; i < arcNumber; i++) {
        let arcRand1 = random(10, random(0.4, 0.8) * (height - combBorderHeight) / 7)
        let arcStart1 = random(0, 320)
        let arcStop1 = random(arcStart1 + 40, 360)
        let arcPalette = [palette[0], palette[3], palette[4]]
        stroke(arcPalette[i])

        push()
        strokeCap(SQUARE)
        strokeWeight(random(1, 10))
        noFill()
        arc((x + borderWidth + (x * (width - combBorderWidth) / 7) + 0.5 * (width - combBorderWidth) / 7), (y + borderHeight + (y * (height - combBorderHeight) / 7) + 0.5 * (height - combBorderHeight) / 7), arcRand1, arcRand1, arcStart1, arcStop1, OPEN, 50)
        noLoop()
        pop()
        stroke(palette[0])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.js" integrity="sha512-+tu0+vUXyZX+S51npa//IN6znNTLZsBoy8mXn9WzHxfBqYMy6gOzzfTK0VqZf9O171RY9AJviHDokCnvEq8+1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if that worked right here in a stack-snippet?

Comment: LIke if they had a p5js web editor built in?

Comment: Yes you just need to include p5.js from cdn. I made your example into a snippet, but it won't work without the missing file "palettes.json" so I made something up

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `noLoop()` function things will start to rotate randomly. You may want to store all those rotation variables in a 3D array  that corresponds to each square (x,y) and arc(i).

```js
let data;
let index = 0;
var my_size = 2;
var delta_angle = 0.1
var offset_angle = 0;


function preload() {
  // data = loadJSON("palettes.json");
  data = {
    palettes: [
      ["#69d2e7", "#a7dbd8", "#e0e4cc", "#f38630", "#fa6900"]
    ]
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  index = floor(random(data.palettes.length));
  arcNumber = round(random(1, 3))
}

function draw() {
  angleMode(DEGREES)
  let palette = data.palettes[index];
  let combBorderHeight = 0.2 * height
  let combBorderWidth = 0.2 * width
  let borderHeight = 0.1 * height
  let borderWidth = 0.1 * width
  stroke(palette[0])
  background(palette[0])

  offset_angle += delta_angle;

  for (let x = 0; x < my_size; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < my_size; y++) {
      if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 1)) {
        fill(palette[1])
      } else {
        fill(palette[2])
      }
      rect((x + borderWidth + (x * (width - combBorderWidth) / my_size)), (y + borderHeight + (y * (height - combBorderHeight) / my_size)), (width - combBorderWidth) / my_size, (height - combBorderWidth) / my_size)
      let arcNumber;
      arcNumber = round(random(1, 3))

      for (let i = 0; i < arcNumber; i++) {
        let arcRand1 = random(10, random(0.4, 0.8) * (height - combBorderHeight) / my_size)
        let arcStart1 = random(0, 320)
        let arcStop1 = random(arcStart1 + 40, 360)
        let arcPalette = [palette[0], palette[3], palette[4]]
        stroke(arcPalette[i])

        push()
        strokeCap(SQUARE)
        strokeWeight(random(1, 10))
        noFill()
        arc((x + borderWidth + (x * (width - combBorderWidth) / my_size) + 0.5 * (width - combBorderWidth) / my_size), (y + borderHeight + (y * (height - combBorderHeight) / my_size) + 0.5 * (height - combBorderHeight) / my_size), arcRand1, arcRand1, arcStart1 + offset_angle, arcStop1 + offset_angle, OPEN, 50)
        // noLoop()
        pop()
        stroke(palette[0])
      }
    }
  }
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.js" integrity="sha512-+tu0+vUXyZX+S51npa//IN6znNTLZsBoy8mXn9WzHxfBqYMy6gOzzfTK0VqZf9O171RY9AJviHDokCnvEq8+1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```